# What does "Put a Little Muscle" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase: Male Birds Belt out Their Song by Putting a Little Muscle into It ...
continuation of the text:
Some male songbirds can sing more notes than females because they have stronger
muscles to make the sounds. Some scientists used to think it was all about how well the birds could force air out of their lungs, but new research says it has more to do with muscles in the songbirds’ throats.

Comment: When you "put some muscle" into something it simply means to do that thing with extra strength or energy.

Answer (score 5):

The phase "Put a little/some muscle into something" means that you **make a forceful effort** into doing something.

However, in this case, i think that the sentence kind of use the phase by its **literal meaning**, which means that the male birds have to put some extra strength to be able to belt out their songs

Comment: It's a *play on words*.  The male birds have an extra "little muscle" in their throats, ergo they can *put a little muscle* into their singing.

Comment: thanks, but what birds have less muscles to sign, male or female? I'm confused because a man above has said the reverse.